# How to create a nested for-loop over zipmaps and lists in terraform resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, nested, terraform, nested-loops, nested-lists

I've 2 zipmaps over which I would like to loop via a **nested for-loop**, i.e. an *inner* and an *outer* loop.

In `Python` that would be very easy, for instance:

```
for i in list_1:
  for j in list_2:
    # do sth.
    print(i, j)
```

## 1) Definition of my [zipmaps](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/zipmap.html)

### zipmap 1: "masked_cidr_blocks_zipmap"

```
dms_ip_addresses = data.dns_a_record_set.input_dms.addrs
cidr_blocks      = [for idx in range(length(dms_ip_addresses)) : join("", [dms_ip_addresses[idx], "/16"])]
masked_cidr_blocks_zipmap = zipmap(range(length(cidr_blocks)),
[for idx in range(length(cidr_blocks)) : cidrsubnet(cidr_blocks[idx], 0, 0)])
```

According to the [zipmap docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/zipmap.html), zipmaps are structured like `zipmap(keyslist, valueslist)`, e.g. (invented values):

```
> zipmap(["0", "1"], ["199.99.0.0/16", "199.97.0.0/16"])
{
  "0" = "199.99.0.0/16",
  "1" = "199.97.0.0/16",
}
```

### zipmap 2: "network_acls"

```
network_acls = zipmap(range(length(data.aws_network_acls.main.ids)),
data.aws_network_acls.main.ids)
```

An example in this case could be (invented values):

```
> zipmap(["0", "1"], ["acl-328ufjf2j3923rjf22", "acl-23489289jf23rf232r"])
    {
      "0" = "acl-328ufjf2j3923rjf22",
      "1" = "acl-23489289jf23rf232r",
    }
```

## 2) Intent to create nested for-loop

Please note that the following is *pseudo-code* which does not work like that in `terraform` (unfortunately):

```
resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "dms_control_port" {
for_each = local.network_acls  # outer for-loop
  for_each = local.masked_cidr_blocks_zipmap  # inner for-loop

  network_acl_id = each_outer.value
  rule_number    = 415 + each_inner.key
  egress         = false
  protocol       = "tcp"
  rule_action    = "allow"
  cidr_block     = each_inner.value
  from_port      = 443
  to_port        = 443
}
```

**How** can I achieve this nested looping behavior within my resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "dms_control_port"
to *populate different parameters with either the outer or inner loop-value*?

Comment: Can you provide examples of your `network_acls` and `masked_cidr_blocks_zipmap`? What the data  looks like?

Comment: I've just added examples, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simulating the double `for_each` by flatting your datasets. So for your example:

```
locals {
  network_acls =     {
      "0" = "acl-328ufjf2j3923rjf22",
      "1" = "acl-23489289jf23rf232r",
    }
    
  masked_cidr_blocks_zipmap =  {
      "0" = "199.99.0.0/16",
      "1" = "199.97.0.0/16",
    }
  
  # flatten data structure
  acls_cidr = merge([
          for ni,acl in local.network_acls:
           {
             for maskedi,cidr in local.masked_cidr_blocks_zipmap: 
             "${ni}-${maskedi}" => {
                   "ni" = ni
                   "maskedi" = maskedi  
                   "acl" = acl
                   "cidr" = cidr                   
               }
           }    
        ]...) 
}
```

gives:

```
{
  "0-0" = {
    "acl" = "acl-328ufjf2j3923rjf22"
    "cidr" = "199.99.0.0/16"
    "maskedi" = "0"
    "ni" = "0"
  }
  "0-1" = {
    "acl" = "acl-328ufjf2j3923rjf22"
    "cidr" = "199.97.0.0/16"
    "maskedi" = "1"
    "ni" = "0"
  }
  "1-0" = {
    "acl" = "acl-23489289jf23rf232r"
    "cidr" = "199.99.0.0/16"
    "maskedi" = "0"
    "ni" = "1"
  }
  "1-1" = {
    "acl" = "acl-23489289jf23rf232r"
    "cidr" = "199.97.0.0/16"
    "maskedi" = "1"
    "ni" = "1"
  }
}
```

Then you just use a **single** `for_each` (example only below - I don't which variable is which in your setup):

```
resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "dms_control_port" {
  
  for_each = local.acls_cidr

  network_acl_id = each.value.ni
  rule_number    = 415 + each.value.maskedi
  egress         = false
  protocol       = "tcp"
  rule_action    = "allow"
  cidr_block     = each.value.cidr
  from_port      = 443
  to_port        = 443
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. Are these 3 dots `...` in the end of the `merge`-statement necessary, or is there something missing I should insert myself?

Comment: @AndreasL. They are needed. They will make `merge([a,b,c])` into `merge(a,b,c)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use zipmap function with FOR to convert list string to map object.
With that you can to use loop for_each

```
data "azurerm_resources" "data" {
  type = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
}

locals {
  account_name = data.azurerm_resources.data.resources[*].name
  account_group = data.azurerm_resources.data.resources[*].resource_group_name

  account_map = zipmap(local.account_name, local.account_group)

  account_map_objects = {
    for key, value in local.account_map : 
    key => {
      key = key
      value = value
    }
  }
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "data" {
  for_each            = local.account_map_objects
  name                = each.value.key
  resource_group_name = each.value.value
}
```